# No recent versions appear in Crashlytics (was "HTTP error 403...")

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

**Edit / Update:**

This error "failed to download settings..." is probably not related to the missing info in Crashlytics since the error is maybe permissible? (Though worth mentioning the error sometimes says `code=2` now and sometimes `code=-5`)

Crashlytics is still not showing any recent versions. Most all of my users are on Version 1.1 build #267, and we are testing Version 1.2. The latest build in the Crashlytics dashboard is way out of date at #239.

At first I thought this was because we started using Firebase without upgrading to the Firebase version of Crashlytics, but upgrading to Firebase-Crashlytics didn't fix it.

Log with debugging enabled:

https://gist.github.com/lacyrhoades/9c8cf5afc6a885fbca1f50cf26170ac6

Noticing this error now:

```
2018-07-27 15:07:06.093192-0400 Fobo[1742:525256] [Crashlytics:Crash] Unable to read identifier at path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4CB32502-DA04-403D-B32D-02FA641F983D/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mvsstudio.fobo/v3/processing/fe3f8bfbbf944c8bbd8c5e847100efe9
```

And the log stops sometimes with just this, no "submission successful" line:

```
2018-07-27 15:09:15.658328-0400 Fobo[1759:527272] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id 'cd8c72a38cb84319b85a1899e03c20b4' for submission
```

But also sometimes ends like this:

```
2018-07-24 15:40:02.098146-0400 Fobo[803:153420] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Unable to remove a processing item
2018-07-24 15:40:02.098322-0400 Fobo[803:153420] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '(null)' for submission
2018-07-24 15:40:02.098677-0400 Fobo[803:153420] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2018-07-24 15:40:02.098954-0400 Fobo[803:153420] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8FB2BC7-59AF-4FBC-92DE-A9081B3E03C4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mvsstudio.fobo/v3/prepared/C3E3C58E-0E9E-4F64-8C74-151EFEA284D1.multipartmime
2018-07-24 15:40:02.496371-0400 Fobo[803:153496] [ImageManager] Unable to load image data, /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2180.JPG
2018-07-24 15:40:02.573610-0400 Fobo[803:153495] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-07-24 15:40:02.573704-0400 Fobo[803:153495] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-07-24 15:40:02.761787-0400 Fobo[803:153405] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8FB2BC7-59AF-4FBC-92DE-A9081B3E03C4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mvsstudio.fobo/v3/prepared/D81E2478-3B94-41AF-9E36-CA57C15D5AA3.multipartmime
2018-07-24 15:40:02.763689-0400 Fobo[803:153405] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
2018-07-24 15:40:02.765011-0400 Fobo[803:153405] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8FB2BC7-59AF-4FBC-92DE-A9081B3E03C4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.mvsstudio.fobo/v3/prepared/C3E3C58E-0E9E-4F64-8C74-151EFEA284D1.multipartmime
2018-07-24 15:40:02.767180-0400 Fobo[803:153405] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
2018-07-24 15:40:03.038615-0400 Fobo[803:153420] [Answers] Attempting to log app_crashed
```

Either way, no luck seeing any of the recent data show up in the dashboard.

**Original Question:**

Crashlytics isn't showing any of our recent versions, events or crashes in the dashboard. When the app initializes Crashlytics, there's this 403 error which would seem to suggest a bad API key or something:

```
2018-07-20 12:49:16.402064-0400 Fobo[6705:3539611] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.5 (130)
2018-07-20 12:49:16.402375-0400 Fobo[6705:3539611] [Crashlytics] Running on iPad5,2, 11.4.0 (15F79)
2018-07-20 12:49:16.421584-0400 Fobo[6705:3539611] [Answers] Initialized
2018-07-20 12:49:16.422921-0400 Fobo[6705:3539611] [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.7";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.10.5";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.7.9";
}
2018-07-20 12:49:16.582929-0400 Fobo[6705:3539664] [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2, request_id=5d6157a905d6cb2859e27e4e3ef8b000, content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. A settings error is usually safe to ignore. If you enable debug mode https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html?highlight=debug can you share the output post-crash and on-relaunch of the app?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @YTerle no, not sure what the error means, still poking around but it seems like this error isn't a real problem? Sometimes Crashlytics says it submitted OK, but even then I still don't see any results in the dashboard.

Comment: Updated the post with some logs from today

Comment: I'm seeing this too. No new versions are appearing in Crashlytics for me anymore, starting within the past 2 weeks. I'm going to open a support ticket. If you've figured any of this out, please let us know.

Comment: Checking in on our dashboard... and same thing still. The "project overview" page shows "crashes" and "users in the last 30 minutes" and "crash free users" – all of that looks correct but under the Crashlytics page, still nothing about any recent versions, and no issues.

Comment: Was this app ever present in Fabric before?

Comment: It was in normal Fabric for a long time yeah, since before Crashlytics was in Firebase. We may have started using Firebase around the same time Crashlytics stopped working for us. That may be unrelated though. (Still no recent versions listed.)

Answer (score 0):

I had absolutely the same response trying to connect Fabric/Crashlytics to my application:

```
[Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2, request_id=5d6157a905d6cb2859e27e4e3ef8b000, content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}
```

While having the same Fabric version as you did:

```
[Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.7";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.10.5";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.7.9";
}
```

**The problem** was that I've switched from one Fabric organization to another and missed one important file that required changes: **Info.plist**

According to [this link](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) from Fabric documentation, you must insert into your Info.plist files next snippet:

```
<key>Fabric</key>
  <dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>**HERE_IS_YOUR_API_KEY_FROM_FABRIC_ORGANIZATION**</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>KitInfo</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>KitName</key>
        <string>Crashlytics</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
```

API key of your organization can be found under https://fabric.io/settings/organizations or at the:

1. Log in;
2. https://fabric.io/
3. Top right corner (gear icon);
4. Organizations;
5. Select the one required and see two labels *API key* and *Build secret*.

[Exmple of selected organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXEOa.png)

Click any label and you'll get the key.

Comment: Thanks! Our project does not have that configuration, but it used to. The reason it doesn't have it, and what I'm suspicious of, is that when we moved to Firebase for Crashlytics (not Fabric) we were supposed to remove the Fabric-specific config and Firebase just uses the key in `GoogleService-Info.plist` ... at least I think that's right

Comment: <pre/>@snakeoil As I understand from Firebase documentation Firebase for Crashlytics is actually Fabric. Firebase itself recommends to use Fabric and then map it to the Firebase project console. [From the firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) we can see by an example that we have to import 'Fabric' as the part of Crashlytics. Even though this topic is called _Get started with Firebase Crashlytics_. 
<br/>
<pre/>I've been connecting Crashlytics for a Firebase project as well and importing API keys into .plist file fixed the problem.

Comment: I have a project that was running on Fabric, and Firebase Crash Reporting, which I transitioned to Fabric only, but then was getting the error reported above.

I fixed mine by removing Fabric and Crashlytics from the Podfile, installing, then reinstalling the two Pods.
I also needed to add the run script of:
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" [api_key] [build secret]

And add the Fabric dict into the plists.

Feels annoyingly arbitrary that that fixed it, but it's what worked for me...
I effectively followed this guide again and that resolved it:
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install